# MySQL multiparameters filter

Tags: mysql

How do I make a filtering engine for my [online shop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_shopping)?

My situation:
I have tables

> /* Stored products variants */ 
>  products_variants
>   (id_product_variant,title,...) 
>   /* Stored parameters with its
>   values */ 
>  parameters(id_parameter, units, title,...)
>   /* Stored connection between variant and parameter value */
>   products_variants_parameters (parameter_id, product_id)

I need to do this:
The user selects `value1`,`value2` of `parameter1` and `value2` of `parameter2` for example, so I need to select variants which has:
`value1` or `value2` of `parameter1` AND `value2` of `parameter2`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
 products_variants_parameters.parameter_id IN (value1, value2) AND
 products_variants_parameters.parameter_id IN (value2)
```

But it returns an empty result. How do I update it to make it working?

EXAMPLE DATA:

> products_variants [id_product_variant, title]
>  {
>  [1,Product
>   1],
>  [2,Product 2],
>  [3,Product 3]
>  }
>  
>   parameters [id_parameter, title]
>  {
>  [1,Color: red],
>   [2,Color: blue],
>  [3,Size: XXL],
>  [4,Size: M]
>  }
>   
>  products_parameters [product_id, parameter_id]
>  {
>   [1,1],
>  [1,4],
>  [2,1],
>  [2,3],
>  [3,2],
>  [3,4]
>   }

Customer checked:
*Color*: **red**
*Color*: **blue**
*Size*: **M**

==> So I want to return all products with color Red or Blue and in size M. For this example data products: 
**1 - Product 1 (Red, M)**
**3 - Product 3 (Blue, M)**

SOLVED:
Thanks this thread:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: Your logic is all wrong. You're looking at `parameter_id` twice. This will only return data where it's equal to Value2 the second one overrides the first one. You could do an OR statement instead of an AND. But there's still a logic issue.

Comment: So how should I do it? Could you describe me schema of query, to gain good result?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to be found all products (product_id) with certain parameters. So you filter with the title or id of parameter and found all product_ids:

```
SELECT product_id FROM `products_variants_parameters` WHERE parameter_id IN (SELECT id_parameter FROM parameters WHERE title IN ('Value1','Value2')) GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Yeah, almost. But it's more difficult: I have for example 2 parameters with values. So I need to select products with values from 1st parameter and values from 2nd parameter

Comment: It is possible to construct an example with sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Ok, I will give some example into my question

Comment: I think you miss a parameter group in your database design. At moment you store two information in one column. Is the colon delimiter (sign :) fix, than it's possible.

Comment: I managed to make it working. Really helpful was this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation